# what is the best framework/reusable app for caching model instances (object level cache) in Django?

Tags: django, caching, django-models, django-orm

What is the best framework/library/reusable app for caching model instances in Django?
(This approach is also known as transparently object cache, ORM cache, 
row-level object cache, object level cache)

The are reausable apps implementing this. The problem is there are to many of them!
Here what I found (probably even more exist):

```
http://github.com/mmalone/django-caching/
http://github.com/dcramer/django-orm-cache
http://github.com/dziegler/django-cachebot
http://bitbucket.org/jmoiron/johnny-cache
http://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine
http://github.com/SeanHayes/django-query-caching
```

I do not want test every library, just want to peek one that do the job, that solve more
problems than it creates ("There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things")

Please share your expirience

Comment: You can find a feature comparison here: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/caching/

Comment: zsquare, I know this link. the problem with this table - it doesn't tell "this package has less bugs", or "this one is stable"

Comment: johnny-cache is the most used and mature one. Ive used it myself without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

About an year ago I've had the same question. Checked about a dozen solutions and finally narrowed up to johnny-cache and django-cache-machine. Used the last one for no reason, both are stable and good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this same consideration, and settled on django-cache-machine, because it supports django 1.5 currently (Summer 2013), and johnny cache has open pull requests for django 1.5 support that have not been merged in. YMMV.